# Standardize File in R - Remove Line Breaks

Tags: r

I'm working on splitting out a file into multiple files based on the first column identifier. I understand I can use my_splits to my advantage here. All is great until I realize that line breaks occur when it reaches 150 characters in the text file that I reference. Would someone be able to share the easiest way to remove a line break when that limit is reached?

One important thing to note..each row has a different number of columns based on the first column identifier

Sample data (far less columns/characters):

- Three records shown, four lines total (450,630,280)

```
450~1234~099~abc
    
630~1234~099~abc~567~123 east st
    SUMMERVILLE CA~qwe
    
280~1234~099~abc~mba
```

I've tried importing the data using the ~ delimiter (read.table) as well as importing each record into one string (column) but haven't been able to find a solution for either method.

Any help would be great! Thank you!

Comment: Are you trying to remove the '\n' after `east st`? Is the pattern always the same for your column identifier `630`?

Comment: It appears that that there are only a select number of identifiers/classes have the unnecessary line breaks (ex. 630,631). The number of columns remain the same for each identifier/class. Looking to find any way to remove those unnecessary line breaks when the line goes past 150 characters.